# Java - spring console application global exception handler

Tags: java, spring, exception, handler, global

Java - spring - quartz application

I have Java application with spring 3.x which use quartz scheduler to process some data.
I was looking at the following article where they defined global [Global Servlet container exception handler](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-part-v-exception-handling/)

I want to to configure spring to catch any exception occur into my application. 
Above mentioned article uses "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite" it is servlet speicfic implementation that's why i can't use it.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention what you want to do when an exception is caught. If you just want to log the exception, you could use AOP for that.

A probably simpler solution would be to wrap your tasks with a class that catches the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The class you mention is used in a catch block in the Spring MVC DispatcherServlet for matching specific Exceptions to handlers.  AFAIK there isn't a class to do this out-of-the-box with vanilla Spring, but there's no reason you couldn't create a similar execution container for your app:

```
public interface ExceptionHandler {
  public void handle(Exception e);
}

public class ExecutionEnvironment {
  private Map<Class, ExceptionHandler> executionHandlers;

  public void run() {
    try {
      // Your app code...
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if(executionHandlers.get(e.getClass()) != null) {
         executionHandlers.get(e.getClass()).handle(e); 
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use a context configuration to set up your exception handlers.  Hope this helps.